# Working with DICOM RT structures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bounding-box

I'm extracting a particular structure to create a bounding box from a 2D perspective and need to return the minimum box that contains this structure.

```
info = dicominfo("C:\Temp\....\RtTest2\rtstruct2.dcm",UseVRHeuristic=false);
rtContours = dicomContours(info);
rtContours.ROIs
figure(1)
plotContour(rtContours,58); %I'm electing contour 58 for processing
view([180 0])
```

What available functions in MATLAB allow me to perform such a task on a .dcm file? I need to retain the scale provided by the image to inform on further steps in my workflow.

[image]

Comment: you can use `bwconncomp` to find each 'blob' (set of connected points). Then you can use `alphaShape` or `convhull` to get the shape of those blobs.

Comment: But you are doing that. You are in theory extracting the contours and plotting them.  Maybe the original data is weird, and that is the issue. You need to show us a [mcve], and din this case it requires a dataset and expected result. As for now, I can only guess that you expect something, but the data has something else stored on it. In any case, a bounding box is just getting the min and max values of those contours....